# Error:(118, 17) error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: java, android

Emulator with minSDKVersion is crashing with

```
Error:(118, 17) error: cannot access zza
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I am using Android Studio 3.1 Canary 5 Build #AI-171.4474551, built on November 30, 2017 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 7 6.1

I am using PhoneAuthActivity.java and its layout from firebase sample code and updated manifest.xml.

Module build.gradle is

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
implementation files('libs/acra-4.7.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-configuration-1.10.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
implementation files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
```

App compiles successfully. Here is another error while launching the emulator

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
D:\androidProjects\EasyUI\app\src\main\java\in\easym2m\easyui\PhoneAuthActivity.java
Error:(111, 55) error: cannot access zza
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: are u using only those 4 implementations?

Comment: @Jorgesys that's the play services/firebase dependencies that are related to the crash itself. Whether or not OP includes i.e. the apache commons lang in the project is completely irrelevant. It works for an MCVE

Comment: I have updated all implementation by editing my question. I also added implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0', but same error for PhoneAuthActivity.java.

Comment: Error takes me to following implementation of the interface in PhoneAuthActivity.java (firebase sample code),   mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {  ....}

Comment: You can remove classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' from your root build.gradle and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' from your app/build.gradle?
These are known to cause conflicts due to version mixing with other compile 'com.google.android.gms:*' lines.


from: 
[https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/286][1]


  [1]: http://Here

Comment: are u using multidex?